# Getting webapi get request out of refcursor

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, plsql

I have a procedure that returns refcursor

```
TYPE TEST_LIST IS REF CURSOR;
Procedure TestProcedure (Id IN NUMBER, Result OUT TEST_LIST)
    IS 
    BEGIN
    OPEN Result
    FOR
    SELECT distinct o.paramNumber, o.paramVArchar
    FROM testBD o
    WHERE o.id = Id;    
    CLOSE Result;
    END TestProcedure;
```

Then the class for DataTable.

```
public class TestList
{
    public long ParamNumber { get; set; }
    public string ParamVarchar { get; set; }

}
```

And the method to execute the procedure, then get DataTable into a list, convert it into a json-string:

```
public string GetResult(long id)
{
    using (var connection = new OracleConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = $"{PackageName}.TestProcedure";
            parameter.Add("Id", OracleDbType.Long).Value = Id;
            command.Parameters.Add("Result", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
            ////creating and filling datatable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            connection.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            connection.Close();
            //creating a serializer
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            //creating a dictionary list
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            //filling list with datatable rows
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            //returning a serialized string out of list
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);

        }

    }
}
```

And finally i have a controller with get request in it

```
public string Get(long id)
{
    return TestClass.GetResult(id);
}
```

I get a banch of errors out of this. I need to get a string or list in json out of ref cursor. Maybe there is an easier way to do it? Or what i am doing wrong in here?

Comment: You should show us what errors you get.

Comment: One error i can see is you are closing the refcusor without doing anything `CLOSE Result; `

Comment: This cursor is returning a data by selecting. No errors in sql procedure - it's doing fine by its own

Answer (score 0):

Do not close the cursor in the stored procedure when you are passing it out as a parameter. It is getting closed instantly and WebAPI has no way to deal with that. Your using statements ensure that when the connection is disposed the cursor is closed since a cursor does not survive without a connection.

Answer (score 0):

The way to accomplish this is to

```
Result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                             select new
                                             {
                                                 param1 = (string)row["PARAMNUMBER"],
                                                 param2 = (string)row["PARAMVARCHAR"]
                                             };
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Result, Formatting.None);
```